# type handling by Jackson/Spring conversion of JSON to java POJO

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I'm using

```
Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE

Jackson 1.9.5
```

I'm using org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate's getForObject() method:

```
getForObject(String url, Class<?> responseType, Map<String, ?> urlVariables) throws RestClientException
```

Here's my JSON:

```
{
   "someObject":    {
      "someKey": 42,
   },
   "key2": "valueA"
}
```

Here's the POJO used to hold it:

SomeClass.java:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "someObject",
    "key2"
})

public class SomeClass {

    @JsonProperty("someObject")
    private SomeObject someObject;
    @JsonProperty("key2")
    private String key2;

    @JsonProperty("someObject")
    public LocationInfo getSomeObject() {
        return someObject;
    }

    @JsonProperty("someObject")
    public void setLocationInfo(SomeObject someObject) {
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }   
}
```

SomeObject.java:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "someKey"
})

public class SomeObject{

    @JsonProperty("someKey")
    private String someKey;

    @JsonProperty("someKey")
    public String getSomeKey() {
        if(someKey==null){
            someKey = "";
        }
        return someKey.toUpperCase();
    }

    @JsonProperty("someKey")
    public void setSomeKey(String someKey) {
        this.someKey = someKey;
    }

}
```

It works.  Given the JSON structure, I get a String value of "42" in the property someKey of class SomeObject

I don't understand why.  Is there some magical conversion going on behind the scenes of which I'm unaware?

Can the conversion be counted on?  Also, i'm not currently getting any whitespace at the beginning or end of the String someKey.  Is that something I can count on as well, since the integer value cannot have any whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code at https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo if you want to really understand how it works.

Yes the conversion can be counted on, yes you can count on their not being whitespace in the String in the pojo.

In a nutshell the fields from the JSON file are read in, then these get mapped to the member variables/setter methods of the Pojos that is passed in as your `responseType`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Is there a short answer to how/why it works?  I am curious but can't read the code right now.

Comment: I think i get it.  Since someKey is defined as a String and has the annotation  @JsonProperty("someKey"), regardless of what it is in the JSON it will be converted to String in the POJO.  Is that right?